# In Matlab Runtime Python3.6 installer not found in order to install matlab python suport for ubunut 16.4

Tags: python, matlab, computer-vision, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install MATLAB R2017b runtime Python 3.6 on to my ubuntu 16.4. As per the instruction that given in matlab community python installer (*setup.py*) should be in **../../v93/extern/engines/python** location.

When I go there Icouldnt see that setup.py file in the location. I have tried so many time  re installing the MATLAB R2017b runtime. 
But I couldn't find that python setup.py on the location.

could you please send me instruction how to install this MATLAB R2017b runtime on ubuntu 16.4 where I can access my matlab libries from python3.6

Answer (score 1):

The python installer should be in /{matlab_root}/extern/engines/python.
Then `python setup.py install`

Hope it helps